# How to access local variable outside a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please help me to sort out below codes-

```
    people.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, people){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else console.log('people nearby:', people)
})

places.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, places){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else console.log('places nearby:', places)
})
```

I want to access and merge 'people' and 'places' just after 2nd brackets closing `})`

Comment: You should assign people and person to a global object.

Comment: @binariedMe ,can you please post an example codes here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in order to acomplish that. Any variable you define with `var` is available to the inner structures. You can define an external var and write it from inside the callbacks.

On the other hand, the real problem you may face here is if `people#nearby` is async, the data will not be available after the blocks you are showing, so you need something to sync both, for example an additional function:

```
var globalPeople = null;
var globalPlaces = null;

function checkWeHaveBoth() {
  if (globalPeople && globalPlaces)
    doSometing(globalPeople, globalPlaces)
}

people.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, people){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else {
    globalPeople = people;
    checkWeHaveBoth();
  }
})

places.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, places){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else {
    globalPlaces = places;
    checkWeHaveBoth();
  }
})
```

Now you can write `doSomething()` knowing it will be called when both results are available.

`nearby` passes the callback an array of objects with the positions, so you process it like any other array:

```
globalPeople[0].latitude
```

Or traverse it:

```
globalPeople.forEach(...)
```

For example to just show it:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log(globalPeople);
    console.log(globalPlaces);
}
```

Comment: it is printing [object Object]-[object Object] , when I try console.log(globalPeople+'-'+globalPlaces) under function checkWeHaveBoth()

Comment: You have to know how the `nearby` method is passing data to its callback. For that, can you put `console.log("people", people)` and `console.log("places", places)` before their corresponding `if (err) ...` and see what the results are? This will also determine if callback is called once or more.

Comment: here is the log - 
people [ { latitude: 20.121099203824997,
    longitude: 45.323101580142975,
    distance: 0.21,
    key: 'cba',
    hash: 3541547314263401 },
  { latitude: 20.120999962091446,
    longitude: 45.32330006361008,
    distance: 0.222,
    key: 'abh',
    hash: 3541547314264474 } ]
person [ { latitude: 20.121099203824997,
    longitude: 45.32310158,
    distance: 0.21,
    key: 'cba',
    hash: 3541547314263401 },
  { latitude: 20.120999962091446,
    longitude: 45.32330006361008,
    distance: 0.222,
    key: 'abh',
    hash: 3541547314264474 } ]

Comment: Ok, it returns an array of objects. I updated my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a global object to access both at a time

```
var mergedObject = {};
people.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, people){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else {
   mergedObject['people'] = people;
   console.log('people nearby:', people);
   }
})

places.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, places){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else {
       console.log('places nearby:', places);
       mergedObject['places'] = places;
      }
})
```

Comment: But how would you access the values outside the functions if `.nearby()` is asynchronous?  One way or another you'd have to wait until after the callbacks have run.

Answer (score 0):

```
personGeoLocation = {};
people.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, people){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else personGeoLocation.person = people;
})

places.nearby({latitude: 43.646838, longitude: -79.403723}, 5000, function(err, places){
  if(err) console.error(err)
  else personGeoLocation.places = places;
})
```

Comment: But how would you access the values outside the functions if `.nearby()` is asynchronous? One way or another you'd have to wait until after the callbacks have run.

Comment: @binariedMe , sorry but the above codes are not working , when I use console.log(personGeoLocation) , it prints {}

Comment: @nnnnnn Do you know any solution ? please help.

Comment: Did you try David's answer?

Comment: @nnnnnn , Yes I tried , it is printing [object Object]-[object Object] , when I try console.log(globalPeople+'-'+globalPlaces) under function checkWeHaveBoth()